# Convert crystal report to jreport

Tags: crystal-reports, report, reporting

Is anyone know any tools to convert crystal report files to jreport files?
I have hundreds of crystal report files need to be migrated to the new system using jreport.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no such tool. Perhaps contact [DataTerrain](https://dataterrain.com/reports-conversion/). They offer tools for report conversions.

Assuming your transition aims at delivering web dashboards and self-service  analytics via a web browser, there are 3rd-party Crystal Reports tools that can automate the generation of such web pages directly from Crystal Reports. Ken Hamady maintains a [list of 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched). His list also includes [report conversion tools](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#convert).